# JavaScript Looping through date range with a 1 second delay

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to loop through a date range and delay going to the next iteration by 1 second. Each time I run the following in either jsFiddle or Plunker the browser crashes.

```
  var current_date = new Date("01/13/2013");
  var end_date = new Date("01/20/2013");
  var end_date_time = end_date.getTime();

  while (current_date.getTime() < end_date_time) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log(current_date);
      current_date.setDate(current_date.getDate()+1);
    }, 1000);
  }
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction as to why this isn't working and how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a blocking loop here. It blocks the whole browser (possibly forever!).

```
while (current_date.getTime() < end_date_time) {
    // do something (it doesn't matter what)
}
```

What you need is `setInterval`:

```
var current_date = new Date("01/13/2013");
var end_date = new Date("01/20/2013");
var end_date_time = end_date.getTime();

var interval = setInterval(function () {
    if (current_date.getTime() >= end_date_time) {
       clearInterval(interval);
    }

    console.log(current_date);
    current_date.setDate(current_date.getDate()+1);
}, 1000);
```

(I didn't check the code for correctness)

**Why does it block the UI?**

While javascript code is running, the user can't interact with the website and often with the whole browser.

When you look at what the browser was doing over time the `while()` approach looks like

```
[while][while][while][while][while][while][while][while][while][while][while]
```

the interval approach looks like

```
[interval]                        [interval]                       [interval]
```

Only in the free time the browser is able to do other things, for example handling user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call a `timeout` if a condition fails:

```
function incrementDate(currentDate, endDateTime) {
    currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate()+1);

    if (currentDate.getTime() < endDateTime) { 
        setTimeout(function() {
            incrementDate(currentDate, endTime);
        }, 1000);
    }
}

incrementDate(current_date, end_date_time);
```